# ffmpeg detect if stereo channels are actually mono

Tags: ffmpeg

Can I detect (with `ffmpeg` or something similar) if the 2 channels, left and right, of a stereo file are actually the same and the file is therefore mono?

pseudo-code:

```
left_channel = read_left_channel_from(file)
right_channel = read_right_channel_from(file)
return left_channel.equals(right_channel)
```

Comment: using ffmpeg on the command line or as a library? If as a library, this is definitely possible.

Comment: as a library is totally cool

Comment: Then just decode the audio stream from your video/audiofile and compare the samples from both channels.

Comment: Will the answer be binary for an entire file? i.e. if a portion has identical channels, will the entire file?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, I want to detect if a file encoded in stereo is actually just a mono file.

Comment: @tkausl Sounds good, I just would not know how to do it

Comment: Can we assume that if a 5 second portion has identical content on both channels, so will the entire file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invert the phase of one channel, then downmix to mono and volumedetect if there’s anything:

```
-filter_complex "stereotools=phasel=1[tmp];[tmp]pan=1c|c0=0.5*c0+0.5*c1,volumedetect"
```

Comment: Thank you @vit. This helped me with a multichannel audio file. What I noticed is that it is faster to output a file and then use the volumefilter on that otput file than chaining filters in only one ffmpeg command

Comment: What should successful and unsuccessful outputs look like?

Comment: mine says `n_samples: 0` and `volumedetect:default has an unconnected output`

Comment: @minseong I'm not an expert, but I've managed to get it working by passing the audio out to /dev/null like in jlainoc's answer (`-f null /dev/null`).  It seems to output a pretty verbose histogram, but nearer the top it directly gives the mean and max volumes.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to compute MD5 hashes for each channel.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel -8 -i <INPUT> -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[left][right]" -map "[left]" -f md5 - -map "[right]" -f md5 -
```

This answer, while replicating your pseudocode better than Vit's answer, is worse in most practical cases; The audio channels could be too similar (beyond human perception) but produce different MD5 hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from @vit, expanding for a multichannel audio file:

First we would generate a "dummy stereo" from the multichannel, then we would use pan filter inverting one of the two tracks.

Then we would detect the mean volume.

It seems faster to do it in two steps than to chain filters.

If we were to analyze the first two channels of a multichannel mxf file to check if they are stereo or dual mono:

```
ffmpeg -i multichannel.mxf -filter_complex "[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0[a1];[0:a:1]pan=mono[a2];[a1][a2]amerge=inputs=2[pair1];[pair1]pan=1c|c0=0.5*c0-0.5*c1[output] -map "[output]" output.wav
ffmpeg -i output.wav -af volumedetect -f null /dev/null
```

If it is a dual mono, output.wav is a silence, with a mean volume of -91.0 dB